# Ember how to render value of key if the key is also an object in each-in

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my ember app, I have the following "each-in"

```
{{#each-in stop.data as |key value| }}
  <tr><th>{{key}}</th><td class="space-left">{{value}}</td></tr>
{{/each-in}}
```

Which renders my data i.e. 
customer_name Test
example_one   New

But I also have data is that is an object (another lawyer) right now it looks like so

drops   [object Object],[object Object]

or

summary [object Object]

And the API returns different data so it can change, is there a way in ember to also render the child data so it's not showing object object

Comment: I would pass the value that renders as object object into a helper that displays the values. For example, if the value is an array, concatenate into comma separated. If it’s another object, show they key value as a string, etc.

Comment: you could also render a component within your `each-in` loop and then pass the key/value to that component so you can do what you need to in Javascript